# Streaming Data - Continuous update of Data Marts

Tags: postgresql, amazon-redshift, bigdata

Hey Data Engineering community, I wanted to have some extra thoughts on a topic I'm working on.

Say that you have a AWS Aurora Postgres database and a Redshift Data Warehouse. You are using DMS to do CDC and continuously replicate data to your Data Warehouse (Or any other tool to stream data to your data warehouse, but lets imagine you are just replicating the raw source tables).

You also have Data Marts and complex data sets derived from your original source tables, on the data warehouse. How can you ensure that the data marts and derived data sets are being updated in a streaming fashion without having to run some sort of batch job that refreshes all the tables/views/mvs ?

Done some research on the topic and I have a basic streaming understanding, but I'm trying to seek expert advice from people that have done it.

Comment: You do it with batch jobs. You want a real-time data warehouse, but there is no such thing.

Comment: Hi @LaurenzAlbe, thanks for jumping in. I see what you mean, but imagine you need to power analytics for clients in a near real time fashion ? Is there really no way ? Why is Streaming architectures taking more space then if you can only do such batch ? What is spark place in all this ?

Comment: I voted to close this question precisely because it encompasses all these questions and more, and it is not possible to give an exhaustive answer short of writing a book about ETL. You can of course have near real time replication to a second database, but that database is then more or less a row-for-row copy of the original, any your analytical queries will be painfully slow. You want to pre-aggregate data in a data warehouse for decent performance. Now it is probably possible to accomplish near real time aggregation with triggers, but that will only work only for very simple aggregations,...

Comment: ... and the triggers exact a performance penalty that you can't sustain on a busy database. Hence my statement: any non-trivial ETL process cannot be accomplished in near real time, and you have to do it as a batch job, so that your data warehouse always has somewhat stale data.

Comment: Thank you for your answer @LaurenzAlbe, it is much appreciated ! I'll leave this open for a moment to have other people's opinion (not that I disagree with you, because I'm not an expert on the subject, but to keep the conversation going)